# Why does this import statement syntax work for me when the syntax in the Open Zeppelin documentation does not?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, brownie

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";` DOES NOT WORK (but is what the [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control) shows and the [course I'm taking](https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ) shows)

`import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";` WORKS (I found from another SO post)

I'm a little confused why the former does not work when it's what the documentation tells me to use. When I run `brownie compile` I get the following error:

`contracts/Lottery.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories. import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";`

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was missing the remapping in my config file. Adding the below fixed it.

```
remappings:
  - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
  - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0"
```